# Tkinter set value of Button's corresponding Entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been stuck on this for a little while. I'm basically trying to make an app that will allow me to load multiple files. At the moment, the app has 6 "browse" buttons, and next to those a corresponding Entry box. I'm trying to make the browse button send the file location string to the Entry box next to it. Unfortunately at the moment it appends the file name string to the bottom Entry box only. How can I get it to output to the box on the corresponding row?

Hopefully the solution will help me to understand how to get the correct values back when I press execute, too!

What i've got so far is below.

Thanks in advance

```
    r=3
    for i in range(6):
        #CREATE A TEXTBOX
        self.filelocation = Entry(self.master)
        self.filelocation["width"] = 60
        self.filelocation.focus_set()
        self.filelocation.grid(row=r,column=1)

        #CREATE A BUTTON WITH "ASK TO OPEN A FILE"
        self.open_file = Button(self.master, text="Browse...", command=lambda i=i: self.browse_file(i))
        self.open_file.grid(row=r, column=0) #put it beside the filelocation textbox

        #CREATE A TEXT ENTRY FOR HELICOPTER ROUTE NAME
        self.heliday = Entry(self.master)
        self.heliday["width"] = 20
        self.heliday.grid(row=r,column=2)
        r = r+1

    #now for a button
    self.submit = Button(self.master, text="Execute!", command=self.start_processing, fg="red")
    self.submit.grid(row=r+1, column=0)

def start_processing(self):
    #more code here
    print "processing"

def browse_file(self, i):
    #put the result in self.filename
    self.filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(title="Open a file...")

    #this will set the text of the self.filelocation
    self.filelocation.insert(0,self.filename)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep references to all the `Entry` boxes. To do this you can change your entry creation to:

```
self.filelocation = []
for i in range(6):
    #CREATE A TEXTBOX
    self.filelocation.append(Entry(self.master))
    self.filelocation[i]["width"] = 60
    self.filelocation[i].focus_set()
    self.filelocation[i].grid(row=r,column=1)
```

This way you keep references to all `Entry` boxes in a list. You can then make sure the filename gets in the correct `Entry` by using:

```
self.filelocation[i].insert(0,self.filename)
```